# No data found exception using oracle olapi

Tags: java, oracle, olap

i started experimenting with oracle olap api 'olapi', but i'm having some issues while running their examples package.
when i run MakingQueriesExamples.java in source package i get this error:

```
oracle.olapi.data.cursor.NoDataAvailableException
at oracle.express.olapi.data.full.DefinitionManager.handleException(Unknown Source)
at oracle.express.olapi.data.full.DefinitionManager.createCursorManagerInterfaces(Unknown Source)
at oracle.express.olapi.data.full.DefinitionManager.createCursorManagers(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olapi.data.source.DataProvider.createCursorManagers(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olapi.data.source.DataProvider.createCursorManagers(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olapi.data.source.DataProvider.createCursorManagers(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olapi.data.source.DataProvider.createCursorManagers(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olapi.data.source.DataProvider.createCursorManager(Unknown Source)
at olap.Context11g._displayResult(Context11g.java:650)
at olap.Context11g.displayResult(Context11g.java:631)
at olap.source.MakingQueriesExamples.controllingMatchingWithAlias(MakingQueriesExamples.java:114)
at olap.source.MakingQueriesExamples.run(MakingQueriesExamples.java:40)
at olap.BaseExample11g.execute(BaseExample11g.java:54)
at olap.BaseExample11g.execute(BaseExample11g.java:74)
at olap.source.MakingQueriesExamples.main(MakingQueriesExamples.java:478)
```

the part that's causing the error is in here (last line) (MakingQueriesExamples):

```
    println("\nControlling Input-to-Source Matching With the alias Method");

MdmMeasure mdmUnits = getMdmMeasure("UNITS");

// Get the Source objects for the measure and for the default hierarchies
// of the dimensions.
NumberSource units = (NumberSource) mdmUnits.getSource();
StringSource prodHier = (StringSource)
    getMdmPrimaryDimension("PRODUCT").getDefaultHierarchy().getSource();
StringSource custHier = (StringSource)
    getMdmPrimaryDimension("CUSTOMER").getDefaultHierarchy().getSource();
StringSource chanHier = (StringSource)
    getMdmPrimaryDimension("CHANNEL").getDefaultHierarchy().getSource();
StringSource timeHier = (StringSource)
    getMdmPrimaryDimension("TIME").getDefaultHierarchy().getSource();

// Select single values for the hierarchies.
//Source prodSel = prodHier.selectValue("PRODUCT_PRIMARY::ITEM::ENVY ABM");
Source prodSel = prodHier.selectValue("PRIMARY::ITEM::ENVY ABM");
//Source custSel = custHier.selectValue("SHIPMENTS::SHIP_TO::BUSN WRLD SJ");
Source custSel = custHier.selectValue("SHIPMENTS::SHIP_TO::BUSN WRLD SJ");
//Source timeSel = timeHier.selectValue("CALENDAR_YEAR::MONTH::2001.01");
Source timeSel = timeHier.selectValue("CALENDAR::MONTH::2001.01");

// Produce a Source that specifies the units values for the selected
// dimension values.
Source unitsSel = units.join(timeSel).join(custSel).join(prodSel);

// Create aliases for the Channel dimension hierarchy.
Source chanAlias1 = chanHier.alias();
Source chanAlias2 = chanHier.alias();

// Join the aliases to the Source representing the units values specified
// by the selected dimension elements, using the value method to make the
// alias an input.
NumberSource unitsSel1 = (NumberSource) unitsSel.join(chanAlias1.value());
NumberSource unitsSel2 = (NumberSource) unitsSel.join(chanAlias2.value());

// chanAlias2 is the first output of result, so its values are the row
// (slower varying) values; chanAlias1 is the second output of result
// so its values are the column (faster varying) values.
Source result = unitsSel1.gt(unitsSel2)
                         .join(chanAlias1)    // Output 2, column
                         .join(chanAlias2);   // Output 1, row

getContext().commit();

getContext().displayResult(result);
```

and in here (first line)(context11g.java):

```
    CursorManager cursorManager = 
  dp.createCursorManager(source);
Cursor cursor = cursorManager.createCursor();
cpw.printCursor(cursor, displayLocVal);
// Close the CursorManager.
cursorManager.close();
```

i'm using oracle database 11.2.0.1.0 with OLAP option enabled and oracle analytical workplace manager 11.2.0.4B
i've started by installing the 'global' schema as instructed here:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/olap/global-11g-readme-082667.html
i verified everything in AWM (cubes, dimensions and mesures), and the data in sqldevelopper.
i've noticed that some of the hierarchies' names have changed so i updated them on the java code
any help would be appreciated !
thanks in advance